# oracle and hibernate cache

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate

I am solving a bug in our company application.The application can be connected to oracle,sqlServer and mysql. when i connect to oracle,i delete all datas from some tables in oracle，I can still query datas from throse tables in oracle.First of all,I thought it is because of the hibernate cache,but when i connect to sqlserver or mysql and do the same,i found the datas has been deleted.I have been dealing with the problem for all day.it is really difficult for me and I have to solve the problem in the next two days,if anyone can help me,i will thank you very much!

Here are some pictures and codes:
these are the codes that i use to query the data from database.

```
 long num = dataService.getAllSum(bean.getDbName(), bean.getTableName());
 bean.setIsTableExist(true);
 bean.setHasData(num > 0 ? true : false);
```

here is sourcecode of the function "getAllSum":

```
@Override
public Long getAllSum(String dbName, String tableName) {
    return (long) this.getJdbcTemplate(dbName).queryForInt("select count(ID) from " + tableName);
}
```

when i am using sqlserver,I delete all the data from the table "NQ_AbbrNMChange",when i debuged here,the num is 0 ,that is right .but when i used oracle,do the same thing,the result is wrong,the num is not 0,it seems that the data was not be deleted,but i found it was truely deleted in the oracle.

Comment: you're connecting to the wrong database instance maybe?

Comment: In oracle transactions have to be committed manualy. Did you check that you commited the transction in which you did the delete?

Comment: Show your delete code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @sstan:I have checked it many times,the database is right.

Comment: @steelshark:first,I deleted all the datas from the table NQ_AbbrNMChange and commited,then I debugged it,the num is not 0,but in the oracle,ueing the quering sql,I found the num of id is 0.

Comment: @steelshark：Here are the pictures

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0wemh.png

Comment: @MikeSummers:I delete the data using the sql language by using sql developer and sql server management studio ,not by the delete code in my application.

Comment: @steelshark:Here are the pictures:http://i.stack.imgur.com/86Yv7.png,sorry,I do not know how to upload the picture.......

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem,It is because I have not commited .I always deleted the data from oracle in the cmd not sql developer.but actualy,the datas just were deleted on the view level,They can be truly deleted until you commited.As for sqlserver,I deleted the datas in the sqlserver management studio which can excute autocommit.Anyway，thank you all!

Comment: this is exactly what I said in my first comment..."In oracle transactions have to be committed manualy. Did you check that you commited the transction in which you did the delete?"